# Is there any way to get nonce accounts of an authorized account?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, typescript, durable-nonce

Is it possible to get an authorized account's nonce accounts by using only authorized account's public key?

I could not find such a solution on github, discord, and in docs. They always use the public key of the nonce account.

I use web3js on my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using knowledge of the following facts:

- All nonce accounts are owned by the system program
- Nonce accounts are exactly 80 bytes long
- The nonce authority's public key is written into bytes 8–40

You can find all of the nonce accounts for which X is the authority using `getProgramAccounts`:

```
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';

const AUTHORITY_PUBLIC_KEY = new PublicKey(
  'A1FGsvF7c87UgjYxDyC22rAKAqchBAcFLSMcAGhECLKV'
);
const SYSTEM_PROGRAM_ADDRESS = new PublicKey(
  '11111111111111111111111111111111'
);

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('testnet'));
const nonceAccounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
  // The system program owns all nonce accounts.
  SYSTEM_PROGRAM_ADDRESS,
  {
    filters: [
      {
        // Nonce accounts are exactly 80 bytes long
        dataSize: 80,
      },
      {
        // The authority's 32-byte public key is written
        // into bytes 8-40 of the nonce's account data.
        memcmp: {
          bytes: AUTHORITY_PUBLIC_KEY.toBase58(),
          offset: 8,
        },
      },
    ],
  }
);
console.log(nonceAccounts);
```

[Playground link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8gxndk?file=index.js).

Comment: Be aware that `getProgramAccounts` is a monster of a query method, and your RPC provider may limit your usage of it, or at least be annoyed by you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, and you are right about how heavy query this is. It took more than 1 minute.